# Print webpage from QtWebKit.webView to pdf PyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pdf-generation, qtwebkit

Hi what i'am trying to accomplish is that, i have a QWidget with a custom QtWebKit.QWebView which displays a particular website. I want to save that web page as a pdf using python and PyQt.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtWebKit
from Save_Evidence import *
import sys

##### Custom WebView #############
class Browser(QtWebKit.QWebView):

    def __init__(self,parent =None):
        QtWebKit.QWebView.__init__(self,parent)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._result_available)

    def _result_available(self, ok):
    frame = self.page().mainFrame()
    self.html = unicode(frame.toHtml()).encode('utf-8')

#################################



try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(640, 480)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.webView = Browser(Form)
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(_fromUtf8("https://malwr.com/submission/")))
        self.webView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("webView"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.webView)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton.setDisabled(True)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(Form)
        self.buttonBox.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        self.buttonBox.setCenterButtons(False)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonBox"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton , QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()") , self.saveReport)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.webView , QtCore.SIGNAL(" loadFinished (bool)") , self.printIt)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Malwr.com", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Save Report", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))



    def printIt(self, val):   
        if str(self.webView.url().toString()).find("https://malwr.com/analysis/") == 0:
            xpage = self.webView.page()
            self.HTML = unicode(xpage. currentFrame().toHtml()).encode('utf-8')
            f =xpage. currentFrame().contentsSize()
            self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)

    def saveReport(self):
        self.webView.page().setViewportSize(xpage. currentFrame().contentsSize())
        image = QtGui.QImage(self.webView.page().viewportSize(),QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(image)
        self.webView.page().mainFrame().render(painter)
        painter.end()
        image.save(QtCore.QString("output-report"),"png")
        output = QtCore.QFile()
        output.open(1, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        image.save(output, 'PNG')




class MyForm(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
            self.ui = Ui_Form()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is my existing code this allows me to save the  web page as an image.  i need to save the web page in such a manner, that i can print it onto a A4 sheet.

Right now the screenshot of the web page is quite long (in height) so it must be represented on more than one page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to save a web-page as pdf, use [QPrinter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprinter.html):

```
    printer = QtGui.QPrinter()
    printer.setPageSize(QtGui.QPrinter.A4)
    printer.setColorMode(QtGui.QPrinter.Color)
    printer.setOutputFormat(QtGui.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    printer.setOutputFileName('report.pdf')
    self.page().mainFrame().print_(printer)
```

**EDIT**:

If you're on Windows, you might be able to improve the quality with:

```
    printer = QtGui.QPrinter(QtGui.QPrinter.HighResolution)
```

Comment: Thanks.

By the way the when i open report.pdf that is generated by the code , it is kind of blurred , it takes me almost 200% zoom to make the text a bit more clearer. Any idea how to solve that.

Comment: @thecreator232. I tried a few random pages and don't get any significant blurring. I've a added one possible solution to my answer that might help if you're on Windows.

Comment: @TheCreator232 : I have try both of your method, save to png and save to pdf. In my opinion, it is better to use the save to png result and then --in some way-- slice the long PNG into PNGs and then combine them to create a multi page PDF. This will create a pixel perfect screen snapping result (which is my intention actually)

Thanks for this post!