# Save Contents of QTextEdit as *.pdf?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, reportlab, qtextedit

I am trying to save the contents of a Text Editor as a pdf file. The text Editor has been made using PyQt (i didn't make the text Editor), i got the code of the text editor from [here](http://thecodeinn.blogspot.in/2013/07/fully-functional-pyqt-text-editor.html). I have done some changes to the editor but that wont be a problem.

After some initial research i found that i need to use ReportLab to publish a pdf file.But i can't find a way to do this .

Does anyone know how this could be accomplished ?

Comment: I've just remembered that you asked a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22352384/984421) that you accepted an answer for. So why do you now think you need ReportLab? I tested the Qt pdf writer on Linux and WinXP and it gives pretty good results (especially with plain text).

Answer (score 8):

The source code for the Text Editor already has a `PDF` method, but it is unused, and possibly won't work properly as it stands.

A basic re-write of the method that should work on all platforms, would look like this:

```
def SavetoPDF(self):
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save to PDF')
    if filename:
        printer = QtGui.QPrinter(QtGui.QPrinter.HighResolution)
        printer.setPageSize(QtGui.QPrinter.A4)
        printer.setColorMode(QtGui.QPrinter.Color)
        printer.setOutputFormat(QtGui.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setOutputFileName(filename)
        self.text.document().print_(printer)
```

The only other thing you'll need is a menu item to run it, so in `Main.initUI` just add:

```
    pdfAction = QtGui.QAction("Save to PDF", self)
    pdfAction.setStatusTip("Save to PDF")
    pdfAction.triggered.connect(self.SavetoPDF)
    ...

    file.addAction(pdfAction)
```

Comment: This works well, and is basically what Mark Summerfield has in Chapter 13 of his PyQt book if anyone has it (though ekhumoro's version here is a bit more worked out in some ways). Works well with plain text, beyond that it gets a little gnarly.